# How to print non repeating element by two threads?

Tags: java, spring

i want to print non repeating elements from the same resource by two threads.

here in below code , am printing repeated elements

```
class TestSleepMethod1 extends Thread{  
    public void run(){  
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){  
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}  
            System.out.println(i);  
        }  
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        TestSleepMethod1 t1=new TestSleepMethod1();  
        TestSleepMethod1 t2=new TestSleepMethod1();  

        t1.start();  
        t2.start();  
    }  
}
```

The output :

1
       1
       2
       2
       3
       3
       4
       4
. I want, if one thread prints "1" other thread should not print "1" again instead it should print 2 . How to achieve this condition?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Queue (eg:BolockingQueue) and add all the numbers to it. Then notify the thread after the addition which should take the values from the queue one by one. This will help you to achieve the result you desire.
Refer http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/blocking-queues.html

Answer (score 0):

**In your case very unlikely to happen because of the thread sleeping.**

Try to use different sleeping interval:

```
class TestSleepMethod1 extends Thread {
    private final long sleepingInterval;

    private TestSleepMethod1(long sleepingInterval) {
        this.sleepingInterval = sleepingInterval;
    }

    public void run(){  
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){  
            try{Thread.sleep(sleepingInterval);}catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}  
            System.out.println(i);  
        }  
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        TestSleepMethod1 t1=new TestSleepMethod1(500);  
        TestSleepMethod1 t2=new TestSleepMethod1(300);  

        t1.start();  
        t2.start();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you please be specific? Am new to java. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
try 



    static int i =1;
    public void run(){ 
        for(;i<5;){  // you can also use while(i<5)
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);

            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }  
            System.out.println(i++); 
        }  
    }  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        TestSleepMethod1 t1=new TestSleepMethod1();  
        TestSleepMethod1 t2=new TestSleepMethod1();  

        t1.start();  
        t2.start();  
    }  


output 
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: In an multithread context you *must* used thread safe structure. Your code is not thread safe because there is no assumption that `i is not cached (eg. in a register) and the incrementation is not atomic

Comment: accept your point, but as per Nandlalji, he wants the same variable to print next values, thus this seems the only way out

Comment: An `AtomicInteger` implements atomic increment, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You must used a shared and thread safe structure which enforce atomicity of the operations.

An [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) fits your need. [AtomicInteger#incrementAndGet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) is an atomic operation. By consequence, only one thread will, for a distrinct value, increment this value and return it:

```
class TestSleepMethod1 extends Thread{  
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public void run(){  
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){  
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}  
            System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet());  
        }  
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        TestSleepMethod1 t1=new TestSleepMethod1();  
        TestSleepMethod1 t2=new TestSleepMethod1();  

        t1.start();  
        t2.start();  
    }  
}
```